# React, SSR response from API requests on Express

Tags: reactjs, api, express, axios, server-side-rendering

I am using React and Express. I am doing server side rendering, for the first load for any of my routes.
This routes are something like "/contacts", "/aboutUs" and so on.
Now I am doing API POST and GET request with Axis and hitting endpoints like "/api/contactForm"
When someone visits this route in Browser, there is nothing there.
Is it possible or actually is there any need doing SSR from the responses that this API gives me?

For example, I visit "http://mydomain/contacts" page and that page is server side rendered. On that page there is button, and when it's clicked it uses Axios to make GET request for some data in Express on a route "/api/myData". I return the fetched data to client and show it on "http://mydomain/contacts" page.

Can the data that is being returned be server side rendered (SSR). I don't see what would be the benefit but to ask just in case?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you explain in a better way?

Comment: I will try better. So there are client side routes like "contacts", "aboutUs", "homePage" and so on. There are also Express routes like "/api/personData". When someone visits this route in browser there is nothing there, but on Express it is used as a GET route to fetch data about some person. This API endpoint is hit from the client side using Axios. The data that this API endpoint returns is passed back to client and showed on page. Can this data be SSR?